# How to use POST method in scala form in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to submit a form which will redirect to another HTML page. But the action method is not working.

view.html

```
@(bookForm:Form[Book])(implicit messages: Messages)
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create Books</title>
<body>
<h1>Create Books</h1>
@helper.form(action=routes.BooksController.save()){
    @helper.inputText(bookForm("id"))
    @helper.inputText(bookForm("title"))
    @helper.inputText(bookForm("price"))
    @helper.inputText(bookForm("author"))
}
<input type="submit" value="Create Book" />
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

controller.scala

```
  def index() = Action {
    val books = Book.allBooks()
    Ok(views.html.books.index(books))
  }
  def create() = 
      Action { implicit request =>
      Ok(views.html.books.create(Book.bookForm))
  }
  def save() =
      Action { implicit request =>
      val book = Book.bookForm.bindFromRequest().get
      Book.add(book)
      Redirect(routes.BooksController.index())
```

Routes defined are

```
GET    /books              controllers.BooksController.index()
GET    /books/create       controllers.BooksController.create()
POST   /books/create       controllers.BooksController.save()
```

Comment: What does it mean: its not working? Are you getting some error? If so, please provide error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button should be inside form tag:

```
@helper.form(action=routes.BooksController.save()){
    @helper.inputText(bookForm("id"))
    @helper.inputText(bookForm("title"))
    @helper.inputText(bookForm("price"))
    @helper.inputText(bookForm("author"))
    <input type="submit" value="Create Book" />
}
```